# Why does Thread.Sleep() freeze the Form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, sleep, freeze

I try to experiment with `Thread.Sleep()`. I created basic Windows Forms application with one button.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoStuff);
        thread1.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            button1.Text +=".";
        }
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
       //DoStuff         
    }
```

When I click my button the `DoStuff` method works fine, but the GUI freezes and nothing happens. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm using .Net 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep the UI active, you need for the main UI thread to service its message pump. It can only do that when it is not handling UI events. In your case the function

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoStuff);
    thread1.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        button1.Text +=".";
    }
}
```

does not return for around `100000*500` milliseconds. While this event handler is executing, the UI thread is busy. It is executing this event handler. As such it is not able to service the message pump. Hence your application's UI freezes.

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.Sleep` just sleeps the current thread (i.e. stops it from doing anything, such as redrawing, processing clicks etc), which in your case is the UI thread.  If you put the `Sleep` in `DoStuff` you wouldn't experience the block as you'd be on a separate thread although you wouldn't be able to update button1.  Depending on the version of .NET you're using consider using the Task Parallel Library, something like this:

```
private TaskScheduler _uiScheduler;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoStuff);
    thread1.Start();

    // Create a task on a new thread.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);

                // Create a new task on the UI thread to update the button
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    { button1.Text += "."; }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I understand that UI sleeps , what I don't understand is why does it sleep more then 500 milliseconds ?

Comment: @GugaMelkadze The UI can only be updated when the `button1_Click()` method returns, and clearly it won't return until it has slept for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Your Thread.Sleep() call is part of your for{} statement, so it gets executed 100,000 times. You currently have your UI thread sleeping for almost 14 hours!

Comment: @GugaMelkadze If you are using a very outdated version of .Net, you should add a tag to your question, otherwise people will assume you are not using an obsolete version, and will waste their time answering your question with an unusable solution.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, I'll consider that.

Answer (score 0):

For that you better use a `Timer` but if you want your current code to work you need to add `Application.DoEvents();` after you update the `button.Label += "."`

Comment: Don't ever use `Application.DoEvents()`! It's evil.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't. I would use a timer that ticks every 500ms

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to multithreading, I strongly encourage you to look at the Task Parallel Library (TPL). It simplifies threading, and gives you tools to help guarantee callback (continuation) threads occur on the UI thread.

The TPL is in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace.

Update: just seen your comment about .Net v2. TPL was introduced in .NET v3.5 or possibly as late as v4.

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT:` After programming for a few more years, I now know how terrible of a practice this is. DO NOT DO ANYTHING I SUGGESTED BELOW. It's all crap. A more proper solution would be doing all of your intensive methods async all together. Regardless, don't do what I mention below.

All The methods above do work however, I do recommend just using an async void.
`Sleep()` just pauses the current thread for `int` amount of milliseconds, and if your whole program runs off of 1 thread, it'll pause the whole program. Don't quote me on this, I do believe that async creates a new thread specifically for that function.

Below I've included a better sleep function.

To call the function `asleep(milliseconds)`, 
replace "milliseconds" with how many milliseconds you wish to sleep for.

Function Code:

```
public async void asleep(int time){
    await Task.Delay(time)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Re-arrange code as following

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(DoStuff);
        thread1.Start();
}

public void DoStuff()
{     
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            //Invoke goes here
        }
}
```

Now you run your WORK in a separate thread and release your UI thread for usual work (Drawing related or other work)

NOTE - Now you will need Invoke methods to change Button text , else you will get warning for "Cross-thread operation not valid"

More on Invokes - [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: You need to invoke the `Text` access as it is on a different thread from the one creating the control.

Comment: I was adding that part in Edits :)